# FATAL EXCEPTION: main android validation

Tags: android, validation, exception, program-entry-point, fatal-error

I have an application in which i want to add validation, but when i run only validation page it works fine but when i rut it with this page it gives me error.
I think i am doing mistake where i am adding an imagebutton by which i call the validation page which name is propertysearch.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
```

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: Put your stack trace of your logcat.

Comment: 02-28 14:00:32.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1136): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 14:00:32.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1136): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newapp.Devyani/com.newapp.Devyani.ViewPagerStyle1Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 14:00:32.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1136):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-28 14:00:32.844: E/AndroidRuntime(1136):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)

Comment: i am so sorry but i am very new to android.

Comment: please tell me that where i am adding an imagebutton is it ok. because when i am running code directly it working fine.

Comment: Add PropertySearch.class to your manifest

Comment: Why have you kept <requestFocus /> in xml file? Try removing it.

Comment: Nothing happen Shreya S...  :(

Comment: i already added PropertySearch.class in Manifest TanjaV

Answer (score 1):

Well the stacktrace says there's a `NullPointerException` at line 32 in your `ViewPagerStyle1Activity`. Look what call is at that line and you should know the culprit.

You are trying to find `imageButton1` in your layout `main`, but it is actually located in  your layout `layout_one`. The fix now depends on what you are actually plan to do with your fragment. You could just set the fragment layout as the layout for your `ViewPagerStyle1Activity` by replacing `setContentView(R.layout.main);` with `setContentView(R.layout.layout_one);` in its' `onCreate` method.

**Update:** maybe you should read a bit first about Android [Activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html), [Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). This is **very** basic stuff and you won't get far without learning it in and out.

Of course you can't find the imageButton1, if you hard-code `findViewById` to return `null` in your fragment.

```
private ImageButton findViewById(int imagebutton1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

But I get the sense you really don't know what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: I think @Thrakbad is right, imageButton1 is not defined in your layout.xml. Please rename button1 to imageButton1, or otherway around.

Comment: @KushalPratapSingh do you actually have a layout `main`? If so then post it in your question above, because in your `ViewPagerStyle1Activity` you have the code `setContentView(R.layout.main);` and without it, we can't know if the button is actually defined or not.

Comment: yes you are right imagebutton is not defined in my .xml but i want it on layout_one file. please check i am updating my question

Comment: NOW PLEASE CHECK MY layout_one file plz.

Comment: in LayoutOne.java file i have an error of (The constructor Intent(LayoutOne, Class<PropertySearch>) is undefined) in "Intent intent = new Intent(LayoutOne.this,
                    PropertySearch.class);" line

Comment: updated my answer again, but I would recommend you to take a step back and start over reading about the Android basics. There's a lot wrong with your code and it seems you are just copy/pasting things around without knowing what you are actually doing.

Comment: Thanks Thrakbad i really thinks that i have to learn more. But i want to tell you that i am learning android from past 2 weeks and its just my learning. today i want to learn something new from home so i just started these stuffs. But anyways Thanks a Lot for your warm help. :)

Comment: No problem, just try some easy examples without fragments first and then slowly work your way to the heavier stuff ;-)